# How to save text input as a variable and then submit to server (ajax and javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, saving-data

I want to save 'gender' and 'age' input as a variable and then submit it to the server using ajax. When I requested it output to the console, however, the gender variable worked but the age variable did not. (This is part of a longer html code)

```
    <div id="page1" class="instDiv">
    <h2>Please select your gender</h2><br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="female">female<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="male" >male<br>
    <h2>Please provide your age:</h2> <input type="text" name="age" id="age"><br>
    </div>
```

And then later in the code, I ask it to print to the console. The console outputs gender correctly but puts age as 'undefined'.

```
subjgender= $("#gender").val();
subjage= $("age").val();
console.log(subjgender);
console.log(subjage);  }
```

My question is first, why doesn't it correctly output the age, and second, how do I get it to save to the server as actual data?

Comment: What are you using for the server? php? asp.net? something else?

Answer (score 2):

replace this it will work you missed the #.

```
subjage= $("#age").val();
```

Answer (score 2):

As said by SRK, you forgot the identifier for Ids in your jQuery selector (#).

About the POST:
To post to the server, you can either wrap that code with a *form* tag and use a standard *input* of type submit, or use a normal ajax post (as you asked), such as:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/YourPostUrlHere",
    type: "POST",
    data: { 'age': $("#age").val(), 'gender': $("#gender").val() },
    success: function (result) {
        //Do whatever you want with the result.
    }
});
```

More info here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/